# How to pass a function to an already created thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am creating a thread in a c++ program as following:

```
threadList.push_back(std::thread(factor, Ap, Ai, Ax, b, Q, P, Pinv, n, 0, 5000));
```

The vector threadList is a vector that has all the threads created in the program. and the function factor receives the following parameters:
 Ap, Ai, Ax, b, Q, P, Pinv, n, 0, 5000

I am trying to use this thread (after function factor is done) for another function instead of creating a new thread and add additional over head to the code. Is there a way of doing it ?

Comment: You need a work queue (or something damn-similar to it).

Comment: You probably want a thread pool. It is not present in the C++ standard library. Implementing your own is not easy, so I'd recommend to look for a third-party library that implements it.

Comment: @Kraskevich, can you please check if this what you meant by thread pool   (https://github.com/Tyler-Hardin/thread_pool)

Comment: @Anas Yes, something like that.